# Displaying Inputbox only when we "Yes" option is selected from dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function FormHooks(props){
    const [showtext,setShowText]=useState("")
    const handleChange = (e)=>{
      const getvalue = e.target.value
      console.log(getvalue)
      setShowText(getvalue)
    }
    return(
        <div>
            {showtext?<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Company name"/>:null}
            <form>
                <div>
                    <label>Are you employed?</label>
                    <select onChange={handleChange}>
                    <option value="select">select</option>
                    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                    <option value="No">No</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div>
                    
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Form Hooks
```

I want to display a Input box only when I select "YES" option from the dropdown. Here I am able to display Input box on "Yes" option but it is also displaying for "No" Option as well which I don't want.

Answer (score 1):

Change the condition `showtext`  to `showtext === 'Yes'`

Like this

```
{showtext === 'Yes' ? <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Company name"/> :null}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const handleChange = (e)=>{
  const getvalue = e.target.value
  if (getvalue === 'Yes') {
    setShowText(getvalue)
  }
}
```

Comment: After the first ```Yes```, you will not be able to set it to ```No```

Comment: @Konrad This is not the correct way because in this scenerio if you first select "No" Option input box will not display but if you select it  after "Yes" option then in that case it will not hide the input box even if you unselect the option.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it, you just need to change the render condition of the inputbox which should be `showtext==="Yes"`

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function FormHooks(props){
    const [showtext,setShowText]=useState("")
    const handleChange = (e)=>{
      const getvalue = e.target.value
      console.log(getvalue)
      setShowText(getvalue)
    }
    return(
        <div>
            {showtext==="Yes"?<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Company name"/>:null}
            <form>
                <div>
                    <label>Are you employed?</label>
                    <select onChange={handleChange}>
                    <option value="select">select</option>
                    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                    <option value="No">No</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div>
                    
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Form Hooks
```